# Проблема с шаблоном главной страницы в WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал шаблон статической страницы. Проверяю - PHP скрипты в ней отрабатывают. Нужно, что бы она была главной страницей сайта. В настройках ставлю ее главной. Отображается только TITLE заголовок, заполненный через форму WP, php и html в шаблоне не отображается.

Из-за чего так?

шаблон делал по такому принципу

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `мои скрипты` добавить статический html. Похоже, проблема в них. Настройте отображение ошибок.

Comment: включил показ ошибок в php.ini,  проверил - работает.

Comment: Убрал из шаблона свой скрипт, вместо него поставил H1 - не отображается

Comment: Если другаю статическую страницу ставить(без шаблона) - работает

Comment: шаблон `<?php /* Template Name: MAIN */ ?>`

Comment: Если в шаблоне оставить `<?php
/**
 * Template Name: MAIN
 */
?>MAIN` - тоже не выводит?

Comment: Если это статическая страница - по прямой ссылке выведется "MAIN" - как и должно, если ее ставить через нестройки - главной, ничего не измениться, будет все та же странная главная страница с шапкой, футером, панелью навигации и в теле поста(статической страници) будет title "главная 2", как она и называется

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с темой. Попробуйте переключиться на другую тему и проделать все там.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2i9v09o3pphgyq/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-04-20%2012-45-59.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Извиняюсь, руко....лю. Всего то надо было внимательно читать иерархию шаблонов ВП 
https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png
И создать home.php (почти дубликат index.php) и в нем все делать, а не мудрить.